# exchange server: how to check database of specific mailbox through exchange shell

Tags: exchange-server

Task should be simple enough, finding out in which database a certain mailbox is stored.

the "**get-mailbox -identity "user@domain.local**" is not displaying enough information

Answer (score 0):

Try Get-MailboxFolderStatistics on for size.  Pipe Format-List to enumerate ServerName and DatabaseName properties

```
get-mailboxfolderstatisitcs -identity "user@domain.local" | FL
```

This assumes On-Premises Exchange 2007 or higher.